# Do P2P networks have disconnected components?

Tags: p2p

Can someone please provide links to any paper/reference that talks about disconnected components in P2P networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found [this paper](https://isohunt.com/release/480949/?poster=&cat=-1). It deals with various P2P networks including kademlia which is the basis of bittorent DHT. It defines a probabilistic metric called routability rather than talking about connectivity but I guess the two things are related. (With high routability the graph is probably connected.) From the paper:

> ... we consider the measure of
>   routability, which is deﬁned as the
>   expected number of routable node pairs
>   divided by the number of possible node
>   pairs among the surviving nodes. ...

[image: Failure probability-routability graph]
<sub>(source: [imagehost.org](http://j.imagehost.org/0431/p2pgraph.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

One paper calls it the **islanding problem**, another calls it **isolated overlays**.

Comment: Can you please provide links to these papers